# Add data to UITableView when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to show a list of elements from an array in a UITableView (loaded from database).

The steps are:

1. When I open the view I fetch the data from the database and I store it in the array. If the array has less than 100 objects I perform a call to the backend to get 100 objects.
2. I show the first 10 objects in the table view while the backend call is performed. If there are less than 10 objects I show them and when the call to the backend is finished, then I show the needed n-objects in order to have 10 in the table.

Now, each time I scroll to the bottom of the table I need to add the next 10 objects from the array, and when the table has 100 objects - don't show more  (this is the limit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please not that there are might be many possible solutions to this. Some might be better than this.

- Create an extra cell with a `reuseIdentifier` like `LoadMoreCell`, which should appear at the end of your table.
- Implement `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`.
- In this check if the `reuseIdentifier` is `LoadMoreCell`.
- If it is, call your method that requests data.

Comment: I think it is about willDisplayCell and numberOfRowsInSection methods, but I am not sure about how to "play" with them. I will try

Comment: If i'm right, you an array whose count you're returning from `numberOfRowsInSection`. Simply return +1 from there. In `cellForRow...`, add an `if`to check if `indexPath.row` corresponds to an index in your array. If yes, return your cell, if not, return the load more cell.